# Getting variable out in workspace from function

Tags: matlab

When I am running a function, i do not get all variables out in
work-space. When i set breakpoints than only i am able to get
variables in workspace. Therefore, how to get variables out in workspace without setting breakpoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
assignin('base','variablename',value);
```

to write variables from your Function-Workspace to your base-workspace.
When you use breakpoints you get to see the Workspace of the function or script that the execution stopped at. You can also choose in your Editor which Workspace(stack) you want to see in the debug mode.
If you want to write your whole Function-Workspace into your base-workspace (which in the sense of encapsulation is not recommended) you can use

```
vars=whos;
for k=1:length(vars)
   assignin('base', vars(k).name, eval(vars(k).name));
end
```

Answer (score 5):

While the `assignin` trick is handy in certain situations, one should generally not make a habit of non-explicitly 'poofing' variables across namespaces. The more obvious first approach should be to [specify outputs to your function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html), which is basic MATLAB syntax.

If you have a small number of outputs, you can specify them individually. For example:

```
function [c, d] = trialcode(a, b)
% Simple summation
c = a + b;
% Simple product
d = a * b;
end
```

If you have many outputs, once approach is to store the desired outputs into a [structure](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/structures.html) or [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) so you are outputting a single variable rather than having to specify every output. Tweaking the above example:

```
function [output] = trialcode(a, b)
% Simple summation
output.c = a + b;
% Simple product
output.d = a * b;
end
```